# How to add div block correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which change simple text to textarea field:

```
        $('.field').live({      
            mouseenter:
                function()
                {
                    title='<?php echo $user_title; ?>';
                    old_value=$(this).text();
                    item_id=$(this).attr('id');
                    item=$(this).parent('td');
                    height=event.target.offsetHeight;
                    width=event.target.parentNode.offsetWidth;
                    new_value=(old_value=='Not translated') ? '' : old_value;
                    $(this).empty();
                    var field=(title=='Login') ? "<textarea style='vertical-align: middle; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; width: 212px;' id='new_value' name='term'>" + new_value + "</textarea>" 
                                : "<textarea style='vertical-align: middle; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; width: 212px;' id='new_value' name='term'>" + new_value + "</textarea><div id='save_button' class='btn btn-primary' href='#'>>></div>";
                    $(this).html(field);
                    $("#new_value").height(height);
                    button_id=item_id.split('/')[0];
                    button_id=button_id.replace(/([!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~])/g, "\\$1");
                    $("#"+button_id).show();

                    $("#new_value").click(function()
                    {
                        if (title=='Login') 
                            window.location.replace('<?php echo $fb_url?>');
                    });
                },
            mouseleave:
                function()
                {
                    $(this).empty();
                    $(this).html(old_value);
                    $("#"+button_id).hide();
                    alert($(this).html());
                }
            }
        );
```

**div block for text:**

```
echo "<td width='250'><div class='field' id='".$record['translate']['label_value']."/".$record['language_id']."'>".
strip_tags($record['translate']['coalesce(loc.language_value)'])."</div>";
```

**It works correcly, but I need to add additional div block:**

```
echo "<td width='250'><div class='field' id='".$record['translate']['label_value']."/".$record['language_id']."'><div style='width: 200px;'>".
strip_tags($record['translate']['coalesce(loc.language_value)'])."</div></div>";
```

After this action my code doesn't work! It changes text to textarea field, but in "mouseleave" event it doesn't work `$(this).empty()` construction! Please, tell me, how can I fix it?

Comment: Ehm, you can't run php functions from Javascript.

Comment: have you ever tried to close TD tag just after div?

Comment: Please, tell me, what do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, was just gonna write that in an answer. You must close the td tag with `</td>`

Comment: Please anybody make an answer that I can look at the right code.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the  tag

```
echo "<td width='250'><div class='field' id='".$record['translate']['label_value']."/".$record['language_id']."'><div style='width: 200px;'>".strip_tags($record['translate']['coalesce(loc.language_value)'])."</div></div></td>";
```

I added  at the end

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't added all code, there is closed tag already.

Comment: Perhaps posting the generated HTML will help.

Answer (score 0):

you must close TD tag just after closing DIV tag.

```
echo "<td width='250'><div class='field' id='".$record['translate']['label_value']."/".$record['language_id']."'>".
                                        strip_tags($record['translate']['coalesce(loc.language_value)'])."</div>";
```

You have just forgotten to close TD tag and also id attribute's single quote.

```
  echo "<td width='250'><div class='field' id='".$record['translate']['label_value']."/".$record['language_id']."'>".strip_tags($record['translate']['coalesce(loc.language_value)'])."'</div></td>";
```

it should works like this. be sure all your html tags and attributes are valid.